# How to query for file names starting with specific combinations of letters on foobar2000?

Tags: foobar2000

Went through the query syntax wiki but could not figure this one out.

How do I query file names that start with a specific combination of letters, for instance, finding file names on your library that start with "TT".

Comment: I haven't used F2K in a couple of years but it should be something close to `%filename% IS tt*`, IIRC.

Comment: @JC2k8 You can put this as answer. I can confirm that your query is working like the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%filename% IS tt*`. The asterisk is a wildcard that matches zero or more characters.

If you wanted to look for filenames ending with `xyz` you would use this pattern: `%filename% IS *xyz`.

For the sake of completeness, you can use `%filename% IS *tt*` to search for files *containing* `tt` somewhere in the filename. Just in case you don't like wildcards, you can achieve the same result by using `%filename% HAS tt`.